# Angular Ionic 3 Form Builder validation message in a right way

Tags: angular, validation, ionic-framework, ionic3, formbuilder

This question may be duplicated but I tried googling for the right way or solution for this question. So the question is very simple as said in the title. How to show **validation error messages** in **Angular 4** `formBuilder` but in the clean structure or proper way.

I had a existing code that show **validation errors** in the form but in a hardcoded way or a messy code stucture. Here is my code below

**html file**

```
 <ion-input #firstName class="input-cover" (tap)="focusToTopFields('firstName')" id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name *"
            [class.invalid]="form.controls['firstName'].errors && (form.controls['firstName'].dirty || form.controls['firstName'].touched)"
            [class.valid]="!form.controls['firstName'].errors && (form.controls['firstName'].dirty || form.controls['firstName'].touched)"></ion-input>

            <!-- Validation for First Name -->
            <div *ngIf="form.controls['firstName'].errors && (form.controls['firstName'].dirty || form.controls['firstName'].touched)">
              <small class="error-message" *ngIf="form.controls['firstName'].errors.required">
                First name is required.
              </small>
              <small class="error-message" *ngIf="form.controls['firstName'].errors.minlength">
                First name must be atleast 3 characters long.
              </small>
              <small class="error-message" *ngIf="form.controls['firstName'].errors.pattern">
                First name cannot accept numeric characters or special characters.
              </small>
            </div>
```

**ts file**

Inside the **formBuilder group**

```
firstName: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(40), Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z ]*"), Validators.required])],
```

Now the code still can be understand what is going on. But imagine how will this look like if I had a large form to fill in huge amount of input field. This will be unmaintainable or become a mess.

Yes I could use some components to display the **error messages** via `Input decorator` but I am still finding a way how to not hardcode all the validation messages in my **html file**

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We agree on this, when we add validation message for any reactive form, we need to consider dirty and errors. You are handling 3 validations required, minLength and pattern. So you will have lengthy Condition and each validator specific messsage.

On thing you can do this, move the validation condition logic to component and call from template.

```
<ion-input #firstName class="input-cover" (tap)="focusToTopFields('firstName')" id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name *"
            [class.invalid]="isFormFieldDirty('firstName')"
            [class.valid]="!isFormFieldDirty('firstName')"></ion-input>

            <!-- Validation for First Name -->
            <div *ngIf="isFormFieldDirty('firstName')">
              <small class="error-message" *ngIf="form.controls['firstName'].errors.required">
                First name is required.
              </small>
              <small class="error-message" *ngIf="form.controls['firstName'].errors.minlength">
                First name must be atleast 3 characters long.
              </small>
              <small class="error-message" *ngIf="form.controls['firstName'].errors.pattern">
                First name cannot accept numeric characters or special characters.
              </small>
            </div>
```

**Component:**

```
isFormFieldDirty(fieldName: string){
     return this.formGroup.get('fieldName').errors && this.formGroup.get('fieldName').dirty && this.formGroup.get('fieldName').touched;
}
```

Comment: But if I remove the touch the error already display the error even if I'm not doing anything to the input field. I only want to display the errors when it's been touched. It also shows the green border when the class is valid even If I don't touch the form. I only want to display the error message or set the class to valid if it is touched and the error is gone.

Comment: dirty should take.

Comment: Didn't work for me the valid class is already showing at first load of the page